# Where can I find information on how many PenniesCENT have already been mined?

Tags: websites, altcoin

I saw a request to add CENT on coinmarketcap. Where can I find out the total of PenniesCENT mined so far?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a question aimed at the community, but at a certain person.

Comment: There, I rephrased it to be directed at the general public. @cryptodude No need to be insulting over justified comments. Feel free to rollback/further edit your question, if you feel that I changed its intent.

Comment: Agree the question is more on-topic after edit. But please, @cryptodude, ¿could you delete that terrible ad-hominem? No need to start your virtual presence at this site with the left foot, with name calling and that.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Pennies [CENT] F.A.Q.](http://centcoin.org/pennies-cent-f-a-q/):

> **How many coins have been created so far?**
>
> By the 1-8-2014 there will be somewhere in the region of 60 trillion CENT minted. At the 0.00000001 trade price on Cryptsy that gives it a market cap of around $15-20 million, each CENT worth around $0.00000003

However, there appears to be some question as to the continued viability of this coin. For example, the [extremely long thread here about Pennies](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=359000.0) appears to conclude with discussions regarding its disappearance from exchanges.